# why RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded removed after nodejs server restarts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I face one major issue of  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded  from last month.

If I restart node server, then this error removed and this error arise after one day or two days.

> Error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at disabled (/home/myapp/public_html
/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/debug/debug.js:65:20)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/home
/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:307:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home
/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function
.process_params (/home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)<br
> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271
:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle_error (/home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib
/router/layer.js:67:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules
/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules
/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/home/myapp/public_html
/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/home/myapp/public_html
/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle_error (/home
/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix
 (/home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at
 /home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function
.process_params (/home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)<br
> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271
:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle_error (/home/myapp/public_html/node/node_modules/express/lib
/router/layer.js:67:12)
```

> dependencies

```
"nodejs"   => "version": "v6.2.2",
"express"  => "version": "4.13.4",
"mongoose" => "version": "4.4.4",
"mongodb"  => "version": "2.4.9"
```

I thing this error arise from expressjs middleware.

can any ony help me to resolve this error?

Comment: I think you have a really large `array`, check your DB code, don't store any data from DB in variables or for each on them

Comment: Thank for help, but if this issue arise form large array DB code, then why this error arise after one or two days.and this error display in random pages.

Comment: must be a lot of APIs, on of them is not popular, not called every day, or maybe it must be from a query for search, there must be a condition you get all of the database's data